# Get first date of month in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to get the distinct months between start and end date. The selected month date would be the first date of the corresponding month. For example, my start date is 01/30/2015 00:00:00 & end date is 11/30/2015 23:59:59

### Query I created as :

```
with data1 as(
select to_date('01/30/2015 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+level-1 dt 
  from dual
connect by level <= to_date('11/30/2015 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')-to_date('01/30/2015 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+1)
select  distinct trunc(dt,'MM') as date1
  from data1
 where dt between to_date('01/30/2015 00:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('11/30/2015 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
   and trunc(dt,'MM') <= to_date('11/30/2015 23:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 order by trunc(dt,'MM')
```

## Output:

```
01/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
02/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
03/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
04/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
05/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
06/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
07/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
08/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
09/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
10/01/2015 00:00:00  ,
11/01/2015 00:00:00
```

This query result in a correct output, but I have a doubt that the above query will run in all versions of oracle database without any issue. Please give me instructions.

Comment: This query will run on versions beginning from 9.2, since `WITH` clause isn't supported on earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will work. But using [`ADD_MONTHS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) allows for the same results with much less work in a more direct way.

```
select trunc(add_months(date '2015-01-30', level - 1), 'MONTH') as THE_MONTH
from dual
connect by trunc(add_months(date '2015-01-30', level - 1), 'MONTH')
    <= date '2015-11-30'
order by THE_MONTH
```

Comment: @Prabha take special note of how add_months behaves: `If date is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of date, then the result is the last day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same day component as date.`